# Background image does not work when sending email with Microsoft Graph Rest API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

- When I try to send html email having background image with Microsoft Graph API, it doesn't show the background image in actual mail. What am I missing here? If background-images not support what is the alternative solution to show text over image in Microsoft graph-email?
- Graph API Json Body Request Body

```
{
    "senderAddress": "sender@abc.com",
    "requestBody": {
        "message": {
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "address": "receiver@abc.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                    "name": "backgroundImage",
                    "contentId": "backgroundImage",
                    "isInline": true,
                    "contentBytes": "Valid Base 64 String",
                    "contentType": "image/png"
                }
            ],
            "subject": "Test Mail",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "  <div style=\"background-image: url('cid:backgroundImage')\">\r\n    <h1>Hello, World!<\/h1>\r\n    <p>This is the body of the email.<\/p>\r\n  <\/div>"
            },
            "hasAttachments": true
        }
    }
}
```

- Email received

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and successfully send a mail with a background image using Microsoft-graph Rest API.**

You can use the below sample json code format to send a mail with the background image.

**`json`**

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Test email with HTML body and image attachment",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "HTML",
      "content":"<html><body><h2>Background Image</h2><p>A background image for a p element:</p><p style=\"background-image: url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-pastel-sky-background_23-2148902771.jpg?w=2000');\">You can specify background images<br>for any visible HTML element.<br>In this example, the background image<br>is specified for a p element.<br>By default, the background-image<br>will repeat itself in the direction(s)<br>where it is smaller than the element<br>where it is specified. (Try resizing the<br>browser window to see how the<br>background image behaves.</p></body></html>"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "recepientmail.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "name": "image.png",
        "contentType": "image/png",
        "contentBytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAM1VdVNWgIoSiKeUwsxRYnb2juufffhj//zvffpn/s+8u5sWcxgVDo",
        "isInline": true,
        "contentId": "myimage"
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

**Postman:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]